# How to display one field next to other field use simple_form and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

My form currently have two fields, dropdown list and an input field. This is my code for form:

```
<div class="offset3 span6">
... # other code not relevant
<div id="topic_questions">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :topic_questions do |tq| %>
    <%= tq.link_to_remove "Remove below topic" %> <br><br>
    <%= tq.association :topic, collection: @topics, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>
    <%= tq.input :number_question, label: 'Number of questions' %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a topic", :topic_questions %></p>
</div> #topic_questions
</div>
```

This is how form look like:

[image]

But I want field input has label `Number of questions` will be next to dropdownlist `Choose a topic`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution, this is my new code:

```
<div id="topic_questions">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :topic_questions do |tq| %>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span6"><%= tq.link_to_remove "Remove below topic" %></div><br><br>
    <div class="span3"> <%= tq.association :topic, collection: @topics, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %></div>
    <%= tq.input :number_question, placeholder: 'Number of questions', label: false, style: 'display: inline' %>
  <% end %>
   </div> # .row
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a topic", :topic_questions %></p>
</div>
```

The form is look like this now:

[image]